# Blender acting weird and crashing when GPU-rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, hardware

I've been using Blender actively for a few years, but after i got my new 1080 it's been acting pretty weird.

When i start rendering in cycles "panels" starts turning or flickering black, and other windows on my computer who uses the GPU starts acting weird aswell. After a short while of rendering blender usually stops working, no freezing or anything, it just crashes and opens this window

[image]

This is how blender looks before crashing;

[image]

The GPU is new, and is not overclocked or anything like that.

I've been googling around, and i can't seem to find anyone with the same problem, and therefore no solution or hints to what might be the problem.

Also, as a disclaimer, all drivers are up to date, and I've tried different harddrives and power supplies. I am rendering on the supported feature set, and the problem applies for earlier versions of blender aswell.

CPU rendering works fine. The GPU is a gigabyte 1080 WINDFORCE OC 8gb

Comment: I've read people having problems with NVidia driver version 391. Maybe downgrade to an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem; GeForce Experience (or more specifically Shadowplay) seems to be the reason behind all this. Disabled it and everything seems to work good